# `noto` package not loading

Tags: fonts, packages

I'm having trouble loading the `noto` font package.

(I'm using Texmaker on Windows 7, if that makes any difference.)

When I compile the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{noto}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

I get the error message "LaTeX Error: File `noto.sty' not found." in LaTeX, PDFLaTeX, XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX, but when I compile:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setallmainfonts{Noto Serif}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Using only XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX, there is no error since I do have the fonts installed locally.

I'm able to load other new packages so there's nothing wrong with Texmaker or MiKTeX.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: Is the package visible in the package manager from Miktex? And I don't think that the question is specific to Texmaker, so you could rename the title of the question.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be visible in MiKTeX's package manager, no.
Perhaps I've mislead you with my use of the word "load" in my question; what I really mean is "install".

Comment: Synchronize the package database (menu repositories in the package manager)

Comment: If you have the fonts installed for your system e.g. for use with other applications, the second example would work, even if you don't have the TeX package installed. So being able to use the fonts that way doesn't show anything about the package being installed.

Comment: I made a video tutorial (1:25 min) how to install a package under MiKTeX: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OD15rZO_rD8

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: Synchronising through the package manager has fixed the issue; it seems that `noto` was packaged after I installed MiKTeX on my computer and have synchronised it since.
@cfr: My second example was merely to show that I can compile the same document with the same fonts so it's not a font compatibility issue and not a problem with my general set-up.
@Dr. Manuel Kuehner: The video tutorial wasn't need in the end but thank you for providing it nonetheless.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was due to not having maintained the MiKTeX installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Ulrike Fischer commented, this issue was solved by synchronising the package database in MiKTeX's package manager (an option available in the repositories menu). The problem seems to have been that `noto` was packaged after I had installed MiKTeX on my computer and the database had not been synchronised since.